# Argparse: Check if any arguments have been passed

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

My script should start a demo mode, when the no parameters are given. I tried this:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if len(args) == 0:
    run_demo()
else:
    # evaluate args
```

Which gives a `*** TypeError: object of type 'Namespace' has no len()` as `args` is no list.

How would I achieve what I want?

Comment: use try except to capture TypeError, so you know that nothing has been passed

Comment: @avasal, `len(args)` always throws a TypeError.

Comment: Trap for others - don't use 'args' as a variable name if you're planning on debugging with pdb... it's a pdb keyword and will give you blank results while looking like it's instantiated correctly. If you do use it, '!args' in pdb will show you the actual object

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If your goal is to detect when **no argument** has been given to the command, then doing this via `argparse` is the wrong approach (as Ben has nicely pointed out).

Think simple! :-) I believe that argparse does not depopulate `sys.argv`. So, `if not len(sys.argv) > 1`, then no argument has been provided by the user.

Comment: it works and it is probably the better/simpliest way to do it :D

Comment: Accepted this answer, as it solves my problem, w/o me having to rethink things. => bad me ;)

Comment: +1 Much more practical advice for the problem at hand than my suggestion to check *all* the options against `None`.

Comment: Note that this does not work for checking the number of arguments given to an arbitrarily nested subparser.

Answer (score 23):

argparse lets you set (inside a Namespace object) all the variables mentioned in the arguments you added to the parser, based on your specification and the command line being parsed. If you set a default, then those variables will have that default value if they weren't seen on the command line, they won't be absent from the Namespace object. And if you *don't* specify a default, then there is an implicit default of `None`. So checking the length of the Namespace object, however you manage to do it, doesn't make sense as a way to check whether any arguments were parsed; it should always have the same length.

Instead, if you know you've got a bunch of arguments with no defaults and you want to check whether any of them were set to any non-`None` value... do that. You can use a list comprehension and the `vars` function to loop over them without having to duplicate the list of names from the `add_argument` calls, as shown in Martijn's answer.

It gets a little trickier if some of your arguments have default values, and more so if they have default values that could be explicitly provided on the command line (e.g. a numeric argument that defaults to 0 makes it impossible to tell the default from the user providing 0). In that case I'm not sure that there's a general solution that always works without knowledge of what the arguments are.

Answer (score 14):

I know it's an old thread but I found a more direct solution that might be useful for others as well:

You can check if any arguments have been passed:

```
if any(vars(args).values()):
    # evaluate args
```

Or, if no arguments have been passed(note the `not` operator):

```
if not any(vars(args).values()):
    run_demo()
```

**Explanation:**

- `parse_args()` returns a "Namespace" object containing every argument name and their associated value.
  Example: `Namespace(arg1='myfile.txt', arg2='some/path/to/some/folder')`
- If *no arguments* have been passed, `parse_args()` will return the same object but with all the values as `None`.
  Example: `Namespace(arg1=None, arg2=None)`

This object is not iterable, though, so you have to use `vars()` to turn it into a `dict` so we can access the values.

Finally, as we now have a `dict` on hands, we can get all the values(in a `list`), with `.values()`, and use the built-in `any()` function to check if any of the values is not `None`.
To make it clearer: `any()` returns `False` if there isn't a single value that is not `None`, `False` or `0`(check the docs for reference) in the list you've fed to it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This won't work if you have default arguments as they will overwrite the`None`.

Comment: Additionally, `store_true` and `store_false` type arguments implicitly set defaults. The default for `store_true` is `False`, which doesn't break your test (though it will break `any(var is not None for var in vars(args).values())`), but the default for `store_false` is `True`, which definitely will.

Answer (score 13):

Don't use argparse. Instead just use `sys.argv`. `argparse` creates a Namespace, so it will always give you a "dict" with their values, depending on what arguments you used when you called the script.

Here's what I've done in the past:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit()
return args
```

Answer (score 11):

If one really needs the argument number (for whatever reason).
I have found this code very helpful (but do not know how much optimised it is, and I'd appreciate any comment on it).

```
args = parser.parse_args()
print( len( vars(args) ) )
```

This version counts only the -xx parameters and not any additional value passed.

If one wants everything (also the values passed), then just use `len(sys.argv)` as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume the following example to extend Yours for completeness:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

...
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input', nargs='?' action='store')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--length', type=int, action='store')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if (args.input == None and args.length == None):
        parser.print_help()
    else:
        print(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Your Namespace object, mentioned by @Ben, in this example is `args`. From the strings in `parser.add_argument` a variable is created. You can access it through `args.input` or `args.length` or `args.verbose`. You can verify this by executing `print(args)` which will actually show something like this:

```
Namespace(input=None, length=None, verbose=False)
```

since verbose is set to `True`, if present and input and length are just variables, which don't have to be instantiated (no arguments provided).

Also helpful can be `group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()` if you want to ensure, two attributes cannot be provided simultaneously.

For further reference, please refer to:

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html
  Well structured HOWTO
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html
  Argparse module documentation

Comment: Creative . Liked the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I expanded 2dvisio's concept to count non zero or None arguments:

```
vm_opts = parser.parse_args()
v = vars(vm_opts)
n_args = sum([ 1 for a in v.values( ) if a])
```

Comment: This is useful if using unittest to test something with argparse, in that case the accepted answer can misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest case where you want to check whether a single type of argument that is the same among all the inputs has been passed, you can do it in three steps with `argparse` and `numpy`.

```
import argparse
import numpy as np

args = parser.parse_args()
# namespace to dictionary
args_dict = vars(args)
# unpack values from dictionary, pass to array
values = np.array([*args_dict.values()])
# Check if the defaults have changed
args_indices = np.where(values != default)[0]
# Did we pass any arguments?
if len(values) == len(args_indices):
   print("No arguments were passed")
```

The length is used as a proxy to check if *any* or *no* arguments have been passed. If you want to know which one has been passed you'd unpack the keys and check the changed index.

`np.array()` accepts logical operators for more complex cases.

Comment: you can get a `Namespace` with all the default values by using `defaults = vars(parser.parse_args([]))`

Comment: You're right, thanks. You can select a default value from your code snippet :)