# Prevent python script to run without user input any optional argument

Tags: python

Have a python script and using argparse I define some optional arguments that could be given by the user before running the script. I wish to not allow the script to run if the user does not enter any of the optional parameters defined (python example.py -> to give an error message). Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: I don't want to use required=True for any optional argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argparse: Check if any arguments have been passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698468/argparse-check-if-any-arguments-have-been-passed)

Comment: It's a bit confusing (to me, at least). If the script requires an optional parameter to be passed, then it's not optional anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `if` statement with an expression that uses the `any` function on all the values of the argument namespace to test if any of the options is given, and if not, print the usage and exit:

```
import sys
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a')
parser.add_argument('-b')
args = parser.parse_args()
if not any(vars(args).values()):
    parser.print_usage()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Yes, I can handle this case by adding an if statement that uses the any function. But is there any way to do this by using a specific flag when adding the optional arguments?

Answer (score 0):

First answer is pretty good.
Or you could use a simlpe if at the begining of the script.

```
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) < x):
    sys.exit("error message here")
```

where x is the amount of parameters you are looking for.
Otherwise u can use argparser or manually check like

```
argv[2] == "-b"
```